# Calculate cumulative % based on sum of next row

Tags: powerbi, dax, measure

I want to calculate % based on below formula. Its little bit tricks and I am kind of stuck and not sure how to do it. Thanks if anyone can help.

I have few records in below table which are grouped by Range

```
Range       Count
0-10        50
10-20       12
20-30       9
30-40       0
40-50       0
50-60       1
60-70       4
70-80       45
80-90       16
90-100      7
Other       1
```

I want to have one more column which has the cumulative % based on sum of next row against total row count (145), something like below

```
Range       Count   Cumulative % of Range
0-10        50      34.5%   (which is 50/145)
10-20       12      42.7%   (which is 62/145)
20-30       9       48.9%   (which is 71/145)
30-40       0       48.9%   (which is 71/145)
40-50       0       48.9%   (which is 71/145)
50-60       1       49.6%   (which is 72/145)
60-70       4       52.4%   (which is 76/145)
70-80       45      83.4%   (which is 121/145)
80-90       16      94.5%   (which is 137/145)
90-100      7       99.3%   (which is 144/145)
Other       1      100.0%   (which is 145/145)
```

Comment: Do you have any index column to order data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the below steps to get your answer. Please vote and accept the answer, If you find the solution helpful.

1st step - - Create an index column from your range column. I have replaced "Other" Value to 999. You can replace it to much bigger number, which is unlikely to be there in your dataset. Convert this new column into whole number

```
Sort Column = if(Sickness[Range] = "Other",9999,CONVERT(LEFT(Sickness[Range],SEARCH("-",Sickness[Range],1,LEN(Sickness[Range])+1)-1),INTEGER))
```

2nd Step - Use the below measure to get value:

```
Measure = 
var RunningTotal = CALCULATE(SUM(Sickness[Count]),FILTER(all(Sickness),Sickness[Sort Column] <= MAX(Sickness[Sort Column])))
var totalSum = CALCULATE(SUM(Sickness[Count]),ALL())
Return
RunningTotal/totalSum
```

Below is the output that exactly matches your requirement.

[image]

Comment: Hi @sam, This is same as my answer and answered far later me. What is the meaning of copy other's answer with changing the variable and column names and some description?

Comment: @mkRabbani..I dint knew i copied your answer.  The time i read your comments, I coild understand that your solution could not work because of lack ok index column. This was the last comment i read while writing the answer-- "Thanks mkRabbani, unfortunately I am getting all the rows in the column (count_percentage) value as 34.48%. I suspect it is because I have Range values defined as text. Can that be an issue? –"

Comment: @mkRabbani.. PS: While it gives motivation to take credit for the work, but at the same time, I dont like to take the credit from others work. I gave the solution because I felt your formula did not work.

Comment: What is difference in your solution comparing to mine?

Comment: @user13320137 : If mkRabbani solution works then please accept mkRabbani solution instead of mine as he answered first. Thanks..

Comment: @mkRabbani...As I said earlier, i could not see index column in your solution..

Comment: There is no worth of posting the same answer twice, right? where as you posted way after my answer. Regarding index column, it was in my first line of answer I talked about Ordering. And as per OP's data, only a power query editor level ordering is enough for him rather than creating a new column.

Comment: You can point me out with the mistake in my answer. But you simply followed all approaches from my answer and just added one additional step (which I also provided, but in text). People often down vote this type of answers which is basically same as another answer in the same thread. I personally hate down vote.

Comment: One last answer to your question, yes - my approach will work without a Index column. Adding an additional Index column will raise performance issue as well.

Answer (score 1):

For cumulative calculation, a ordering is always required. Anyway, if your given values in column "Range" is real - this will also work for this purpose as an ascending ordering on this filed keep data in expected order. Do this following to get your desired output.

Create the following measure-

```
count_percentage = 

VAR total_of_count =
CALCULATE(
    SUM(your_table_name[Count]),
    ALL(your_table_name)
)

VAR cumulative_count =
CALCULATE(
    SUM(your_table_name[Count]),
    FILTER(
        ALL(your_table_name),
        your_table_name[Range] <= MIN(your_table_name[Range])
    )
)

RETURN cumulative_count/total_of_count
```

Here is the final output-

[image]

Comment: Thanks mkRabbani, unfortunately I am getting all the rows in the column (count_percentage) value as 34.48%. I suspect it is because I have Range values defined as text. Can that be an issue?

Comment: I also added an Index column and used that instead of the Range but still got the same output.

Comment: Can you try after applying an ascending order on column "Range" in the Power Query Editor? Let me know the output

Comment: you are most welcome @user13320137. but unfortunately you accepted the answer copied from me. everything is copied and just renamed columns and descriptions :(